# android programming - beginner problems

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have done everything as it was said in http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html although I receive an error:

```
"emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling '...HelloWorld activity launch'!"
```

I have restarted eclipse and it ran once properly, when I have tried to run it second time the above error have apeared.

I was trying to enable wipe user data option but it didn't work. I have no idea what to do now. Can anybody help me?

Comment: looks like a bug of the emulator, so I don't think that you are doing something wrong

Comment: If helps, once you get the emulator running you can keep it on until you test again.

Comment: Try deleting the SDK and Eclipse and reconfigure your dev environment

Answer (score 1):

go to `Eclipse IDE-->window--> Show Views --> device--> view menu --> reset adb`

Comment: It doesnt work, instead of previous error appears:

...
[2011-05-12 23:44:57 - HelloWorldd] ActivityManager: Error: Unable to
connect to activity manager; is the system running?

Comment: Probably delete your AVD and create  a new one

Answer (score 0):

Try closing Eclipse and then go in your task manager and kill adb.exe then restart Eclipse. Sometimes ADB hangs.

Comment: I have closed Eclipse and killed adb.exe, but haven't changed anything:/